# Material-ui multiselect with optgroup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am having problems with setting up grouped multiselect using material-ui in react. As material ui does not have such build-in component, I had to do it myself.

I am attaching codesandbox example of my code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-sun-2ffyv

The problem is that on `onchange` event the value I get I get is `undefined`.
Yet, I am excpected to get the value instead.

Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend [react-select](https://react-select.com/home). You can check some [examples](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/) with multiselects and a working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yj804nzpv)

Comment: Yeah thank you for your suggestion. I have used it. But I want to use material ui.

Comment: please explain further. what is the problem with your solution?

Comment: @Ido I have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Material-ui select docs:

> The MenuItem elements must be direct descendants when native is false.

You are using div as direct element and MenuItems as children of div. 
To fix this issue, i would recommend changing the structure of your data (I would use isDisabled without changing the structure, but I don't know if you want to use it for something else)

```
const posts = [
  {
    options: [
      {
        value: 'Hello',
        label: 'Hello',
        isOptGroup: true // -> the new flag
      },
      {
        value: "3",
        label: "Ойбек",
        isDisabled: true
      },
      {
        value: "2",
        label: "Чинор",
        isDisabled: true
      },
      {
        value: "1",
        label: "Озодбош",
        isDisabled: true
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And your MenuItem will be disabled based on that flag:

```
<MenuItem
   key={option.value}
   value={option.value}
   className={classes.item}
   disabled={option.isOptGroup}
 >
      <ListItemText primary={option.label} />
</MenuItem>
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Comment: Cool, one more addition. How can I give some padding to the one which are disabled?

Comment: @Khumoyunmirzo Give classname depending on the isOptGroup flag. I have updated the Code Sandbox in my answer

Comment: Anyway thanks. You gave me an idea of how acomplishing this job